# How to update the data-* attrs?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery 1.7.2, how do I update the `data-*` attrs in my elements *when the data model is updated*?

For example:

```
$('el').attr('data-x', 400);
var data = $('el').data( );
data.x += 100;
```

Changing the `$(el).data()` does not seem to push the changes back to the elements' `data-*` attrs.

Why would I want this?  I would like to use the built in jQuery selectors with up-to-date data .

Comment: USing `.data` should work I thought .. what version of jQuery?

Comment: @ExplosionPills .data doesn't update the actual attr it just changes the data for it in the jquery object.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: @ExplosionPills yes it is pulled from html5 data but when you update it with `.data` the actual `attr` tag isn't updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to push data back onto the element's attribute unless you're going to be working directly with the attribute values (such as in a non-jQuery plugin). The changes only happen client-side, so it's much more performant to simply cache the values retrieved from the `[data-*]` attributes.

If you *absolutely must* update the attribute value, you should use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) method.

Additionally, when retrieving data, it's important to know that the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method will try to figure out what sort of data type your content is:

```
<div data-foo="bar" data-baz="0" data-fizz='{"a":"b"}' data-bool="true"></div>

$('div').data('foo');       //returns "bar"
$('div').attr('data-foo');  //returns "bar"

$('div').data('baz');       //returns 0
$('div').attr('data-baz');  //returns "0"

$('div').data('fizz');      //returns {"a":"b"} as an object
$('div').attr('data-fizz'); //returns "{\"a\":\"b\"}"

$('div').data('bool');      //returns true
$('div').attr('data-bool'); //returns "true"
```

Comment: I want to push the object back to attr as a string so that I can use selectors (since there are no data-selectors)

Comment: @jedierikb, you should make a custom selector using `$.expr[':']` or simply use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) method. There's no reason to push changes to an element's data back to its attributes.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
$('el').attr('data-x', 400);
```

Comment: Ok, yes.  How do I push changes made to the data object back to the attr? ( I will update the question )

Comment: oh..then just do $('el').attr('data-x', data.x); . The second parameter can be variable so you can change it however you feel like.

Comment: depending on the complexity of data.x, I would probably want to JSON encode it 1st.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Comment: have you defined that `data-*` in your element?

Comment: e.g. $('el').attr('data-x', '[1,2,3]'); $('el').data.x.push(4); $('el').attr('data-x', JSON.stringify($('el').data.x, null, 2));

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15491/discussion-between-zen-and-jedierikb)

Answer (score 1):

To work with `data-*` attributes, use the `attr(name,value)` method -- same as any other attribute value:

To set it:

```
$('#myDiv').attr('data-name', 'bob');
```

To get it:

```
var name = $('#myDiv').attr('data-name');
```

The difference between `data-*` *attributes*, and the `$(..).data()` function, is that the *attributes* can contain only string values, while jQuery's `data()` function allows you to attach (and later retrieve) actual javascript objects.

```
var obj = { 
  name: bob, age: 27,
  foo: function() { ... }
};
$('#myDiv').data('some.identifier', obj);

// then later
var obj2 = $('#myDiv').data('some.identifier');

console.log(obj2 === obj);  // true!
```